# How to capture an element before a false *ngIf removes it?

Tags: angular, animation

**First, here is a bare minimum example to describe my project setup**

This project is using Angular v5 so it should have access to the most up to date apis in the framework.

Let's say I have a parent component which has a query list of `ContentChildren`

ex.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent-component'
    // ... component metadata
})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterContentInit{

    @ContentChildren(ChildDirective) _children: QueryList<ChildDirective>

}
```

The template for this parent component contains an ngContent selector that looks for elements tagged with the childDirective selector

```
<ng-content select="[childDirective]"></ng-content>
```

Now here is a page component which uses the parent component, and using the `ngIf` structural directive dynamically displays 0 or more components tagged with the child directive:

```
// template for some component class "PageComponent"
<div>
    <!-- 
       This is the parent we defined before 
       And it contains multiple ContentChildren
    -->
    <parent-component> 
        <span childDirective *ngIf="showFirst()">First</span>
        <span childDirective *ngIf="showSecond()">Second</span>
        <span childDirective *ngIf="showThird()">Third</span>
    </parent-component>
</div>
```

---

**Here is the problem I am trying to solve**

In this parent component I want to orchestrate a complex animation whenever any of these child directive elements are leaving or entering. This goes beyond using the `AnimationMetadata` stuff because there a lot of conditions that determine which animations play, so I need to do this in code.

Likewise this animation needs to be orchestrated in the parent component instead of the page component because the animations will be the same where ever the parent component is used, and it will be used in many places.

Normally, I would inject `AnimationBuilder` and build the animation as needed. Problem this time is because the content children are being ngIf'd away, which immediately removes them from the page when ngIf is false, I can't capture them before they leave and run the animation on them. I know if I could use animation metadata here, it would be as simple as using `query(':leave')` but as previously stated, I cannot use animation metadata for this problem.

Seeing as angular provides a way to hook into elements that are leaving through metadata my hope is that there is a way to do this in the actual class code. I am just not sure how.

---

**To summarize**

Can I hook into when ngIf on a ContentChild is false, perform an animation, and then allow the ngIf to finish taking the element away after I say it's cool?

If not, what is the optimal solution to achieve this effect?

Comment: use [style.display]="'none'" if you don't want remove from the DOM

Comment: I would like it removed from the DOM. If this absolutely isn't possible I can work around styles but I'd prefer a clean DOM removal.

Comment: @tt9 did you find solution for this meanwhile?

Comment: @istibekesi I never found a solution for this specific implementation of adding animations for the leaving of an *ngIf element. I have found ways to make animation metadata work which requires a lot of declaration and can be hard to read but it can work. Also falling back to using styles like display: none in some cases had to suffice. One path I havent tried but will probably work is building my own structural directive like *ngIfAnimated where I use the ngIf logic but have the ability to pass in an animation.

Answer (score 0):

A recent comment caused me to look into this problem again as I never found a satisfactory solution. But revisiting it I realized I can just make my own structural directives that emulate the ngIf logic and tack on a callback that can be used for animations or other clean up, and only remove it from the view once the call back is complete.

Here is a quick hacky sample that can be adapted to fit other use cases

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oex7ah?file=src%2Fapp%2Fanimated-if.directive.ts